# Using shutil.copy for backup

Tags: python, shutil

I have a simple script that uses `shutil` python module to copy files that follow a specific pattern (not startwith "tableau" string), and then move from source to destination, but I am getting the error as shown in the image bellow (TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list).

```
# Importing required packages
import shutil
import os

# Setting variables
source=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Workbooks")
destination=os.listdir(r"G:\My Drive\Tableau Workbooks")

# Looping into the files
for files in source:
    if not files.startswith("tableau"):
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
```

The path that contains the source files is obviously a list of files, so why should I set as shutil parameter to copy those files from source to destination?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error says - you should pass it only one destination path at a time -

```
if not files.startswith("tableau"):
    for dest in destination:
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
```

Even if there is only one object in `destinations` it is still a list.
If you know that you have only one item in the `destination` list, you can use it like this: `shutil.copy(files, destination[0])`